# Regex: user pattern this or another

Tags: regex

I have strings like:

```
Name 31X10.50R15 109S RX706 SUV

Brand 131/70R11 NU8 Word RX808

Word 6.00R16 983/222 10PR MONO S+V
```

I need to match 31X10.50 and 6.00R16 only from strings, as you can see there is no pattern like "digit X digit" or "digit R digit" in the second string line.

My preg_match was this:

```
/(\d*\.?\d+?)x\K\d*\.?\d+?|\d*\.?\d+?r\d*/i
```

With this line: `(\d*\.?\d+?)x\K\d*\.?\d+?` I am finding 31 and 10.5 from first string.

With next line: `\d*\.?\d+?r\d*` I hope to find 6.00R16 and took only 6.00

So my regex logic is to match 31X10.50 or 6.00R16 from strings. But second line is not working for me...

what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try `(?<![\d\/])(\d*\.?\d+)[xr](\d*\.?\d+)`, see https://regex101.com/r/1so9DA/1

Comment: What do you need to match in the 2nd line?

Comment: @PM77-1 I don't need to match anything but it has similar pattern to 1 and 3 lines...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew somehow it works, could you explain your code?

Comment: How _exactly_ do you know that 2nd line shouldn't be matched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<![\d\/])(\d*\.?\d+)[xr](\d*\.?\d+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1so9DA/1).

**Details**

- `(?<![\d\/])` - there should be no  digit or `/` to the right of the current location
- `(\d*\.?\d+)` - Group 1: 0+ digits, an optional `.` and 1+ digits
- `[xr]` - `x` or `r`
- `(\d*\.?\d+)` - Group 2: 0+ digits, an optional `.` and 1+ digits

Comment: @andys Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

### Regex

the code worked on any string contained **.** .

```
(\d+\.\d+)\w+
```